# Getting a character's position that is randomly generated which as a string is stored in character array

Tags: c#

I have created a program that randomly generates a letter from a given word which is stored in a character data type array.

For example:

strong and r is generated and also displayed.

How can I get the position of r and also display it?

s - 1, t - 2, r -3, o - 4, n - 5, g -6. The letter r is the 3rd letter.

Since I have stored the word in character array, array by default has its index value starting from 0 and I can't reset it.

I have got r generated, how can I get and display its position without tampering with my character array?

Is there anyway where I can compare the randomly generated r and its position?

Comment: Why don't you make your program randomly generate a position in the given word, and then get the character at that position instead?

Comment: My answer does exactly that, please see below.

Answer (score 0):

[**Array.IndexOf Method (Array, Object)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310891%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is your friend:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(characters, randomChar) + 1;
//+1 at the end because indexes are zero-based
```

Comment: That will not work if the same character appears more than once and the desired index is not for the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't supply any code, let me just show how I would implement it:

```
public static string RandomChar(string s) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.Next(s.Length);
    return s[i] + " - " + (i+1);
}
```

This picks an index at random and returns the character at that index as well as the 1-based index of the character, e.g. `"r - 3"`.

Call it with:

```
string result = RandomChar("strong");
// Do something with the result, e.g. Console.WriteLine(result).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.IndexOf` as follows:

```
var word = new[] { 's', 't', 'r', 'o', 'n', 'g' };
var character = 'r';

var position = Array.IndexOf(word, character);
```

Note: Since arrays are zero indexed, you will need to add 1 to position to get `3` as IndexOf will return `2` in this example.

If you want to show ALL positions of a given character then you will need to create a method to find them (something like this although it could probably be improved):

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf<T>(this T[] source, T value)
        where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (Array.IndexOf(source, value) == -1)
    {
        yield return -1;
        yield break;
    }

    var position = Array.IndexOf(source, value);

    while (position > 0)
    {
        yield return position;
        position = Array.IndexOf(source, value, position + 1);
    }

    yield break;
}
```

Which you can then use as follows:

```
var word = new[] { 's', 't', 'r', 'o', 'n', 'g', 'e', 'r' };
var character = 'r';

foreach (var position in word.AllIndexesOf(character))
{
    Console.WriteLine(position.ToString());
}
```

Comment: That will not work if the same character appears more than once and the desired index is not for the first occurrence.

Comment: That's a different problem & not what the OP is asking for help with.

Comment: I disagree. OP writes "for example" so he might as well have used the word "character" and the letter "r" and then the index of "r" would be ambiguous based on `Array.IndexOf`. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Is it imperative that you do this is C#? Because you can do this using php:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'strong';
$findme   = 'r';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
$posadj = $pos +1; //this will offset because the array starts at 0.

// must use ===
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos which when offset is really $pos1.";
}
?>
```

The results of this snippet are $pos = 2 and $pos1 = 3.